# How do I make Simple Injector prefer implementations of the "most derived" interface?

Tags: dependency-injection, simple-injector

In my data access layer I have a repository hierarchy that looks like this:

```
    <TEntity>                                 
IEntityRepository<---------+ICustomerRepository
        ^                            ^        
        |                            |        
        |                            |        
        |                            |        
        +                            |        
    <TEntity>                        +        
 EntityRepository<----------+CustomerRepository
```

The `IEntityRepository<TEntity>` interface defines basic CRUD operations that will be useful regardless of entity type. `EntityRepository<TEntity>` is a concrete implementation of these operations.

In addition, there are repository types for operations that are specific to a particular entity. In the example above, I have a `Customer` entity, and the `ICustomerRepository` interface defines operations such as `GetByPhoneNumber`. The `ICustomerRepository` also derives from `IEntityRepository<Customer>`, so that the common CRUD operations will also be available for an instance of `ICustomerRepository`. Finally, `CustomerRepository` is the concrete implementation for the `ICustomerRepository` operations, and it also inherits from `EntityRepository<Customer>` for the common operations implementation.

So, going over to my actual question: I use Simple Injector to inject instances into my application. I register each of the specialized repository types in my container: `CustomerRepository` as the implementation of `ICustomerRepository` and so on.

To ensure new entity types can be added to the system and used without needing to create a new, concrete repository implementation as well, I would like to be able to serve the base `EntityRepository<>` implementation when an `IEntityRepository<>` of the new entity is requested. I've understood I can use the `RegisterOpenGeneric` method for this.

What I can't figure out is, when a generic repository is requested, how can I serve the specialized repository for that type if it exists, and the generic repository only as a fallback?

For example, let's say I do this in my application:

```
container.Register<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IEntityRepository<>), typeof(EntityRepository<>));
```

Most of the classes relying on repositories would request the `ICustomerRepository`directly. However, there could be a class in my application requesting the base interface, like this:

```
public ContractValidator(IEntityRepository<Customer> customerRepository,
                         IEntityRepository<Contract> contractRepository)
{
    ...
```

What happens in the example above is:

- `customerRepository` gets an instance of `EntityRepository<Customer>`
- `contractRepository` gets an instance of `EntityRepository<Contract>`

What I want to happen is:

- `customerRepository` gets an instance of `CustomerRepository`
- `contractRepository` gets an instance of `EntityRepository<Contract>`

Is there any way to inform Simple Injector's resolution that if a derivation of a particular interface exists, this should be served instead? So for `IDerived : IBase`, requests for `IBase` should return an implementation of `IDerived` if it exists. And I don't want this resolution across the board, just for these repositories. Can it be done in a reasonable way, or would I need to manually iterate through all the registrations in the `RegisterOpenGeneric` predicate and check manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your classes look like this

```cs
public class CustomerRepository : 
    ICustomerRepository, 
    IEntityRepository<Customer> { }
```

You can register all the generic implementations of `IEntityRepository<>` using `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` and the fallback registration stays the same.

**UPDATE: Updated with v3 syntax**

```cs
// Simple Injector v3.x
container.Register<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
container.Register(
    typeof(IEntityRepository<>), 
    new[] { typeof(IEntityRepository<>).Assembly });
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IEntityRepository<>),
    typeof(EntityRepository<>),
    c => !c.Handled);
```

```cs
// Simple Injector v2.x
container.Register<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IEntityRepository<>), 
    new[] { typeof(IEntityRepository<>).Assembly });
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IEntityRepository<>),
    typeof(EntityRepository<>));
```

But you should note that if you use any lifestyle then these separate registrations may not resolve as you would expect. This is known as a [torn lifestyle](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tornlifestyle.html).

Comment: This does seem to solve it for me. Like you commented on the other answer, this does introduce the torn lifestyle issue, and I could get multiple instances of a repository in my application. I don't believe this will cause any harm in my case, as the repositories are thin abstractions over an underlying thread-safe service which only has one instance. But it's still not ideal, and something to keep in mind for future changes to the architecture. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `RegisterOpenGeneric` or `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` for this. You will have to hand-write some code to reflect over the type system and find the implementations to register by their specific interface.

In my opinion however you should not have custom repository. These one-to-obe mappings are cause you these grief and besides, you are violating the SOLID principles by doing so. If you can, consider a design as described  [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Comment: It appears `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` would work if it had an overload that let me specify an explicit lifestyle other than transient. Is there a good reason why such an overload doesn't exist?

Other than that, I did read the article you linked and I agree that the proposed architecture adheres better to the SOLID principles. Unfortunately there's no scope for such a refactoring now, so I'll have to make it work with the current architecture.

Comment: @MartinWedvich: Please look more closely. There are overloads that accept `Lifestyle`.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right, I'm sorry! I confused myself with the order of the parameters as the `RegisterOpenGeneric` method adds the `Lifestyle` parameter at the end while it's in between the types for `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric`. Thank you!

Comment: @Martin: we will actually improve this in v3.

Comment: @MartinWedvich, as I mentioned in my answer, please take care when double registering the same service for multiple implementations with any lifestyle other than transient; when you come to `Verify` your configuration it will warn of [torn lifestyle](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tornlifestyle.html) violations.